# How to configure Blazor Server App and Web Api to use same domain?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server App and a Web Api. Both are in the same solution but configured as seperate projects. Both use .net 5. Each uses its own configured authentication using AspNetCore.Identity but the Web Api also has JwtBearer. I would like to be able to run this so that both projects will use the same domain name [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) and [www.abc.com/api](http://www.abc.com/api) respectively. Can anyone guide me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: One option would be to deploy the api to sub-app, e.g. :www.api.abc.com.

Comment: You could use a proxy like Yarp to keep same origin

Comment: What system do you intend to deploy the apps to? Windows, Linux? I'm running the exact same combo (Blazor Server UI, ASP.NET API) on a linux (CentOS) machine using nginx. Hit me up if you want to know more about that.

Comment: We intend to deploy to Windows IIS. Any info you can share would be helpful.

Comment: I'm running the API and Web app on the server on localhost:5000 and localhost:5001 respectively and using nginx proxy pass to make the API and Web app available as myapp.com/api and myapp.com. Very similar to what @fuzzybear said.